# Is there a formatter/beautifier for NGINX config files?

Tags: nginx, formatting, config

I know this may sound a little stupid, but one of my NGINX config files is a piece of crap when it comes to formatting. It works and all but that's about it.

I tried to find some kind of beautifier or formatter, like http://jsbeautifier.org/ but then for nginx config files instead of javascript, but no luck so far.

I hope anyone would have a suggestion. There are no requirements, as long as it can format quickly / lazily made NGINX config files!

Thanks!

Comment: A good static analysis code quality tool should help with more than just formatting. It should guide us to create good code. Having one tool for static analysis means fewer dependencies, less to maintain, less boundaries where things can break. Gixy seems like a good nginx static analysis tool: https://github.com/yandex/gixy (If you are working in pure javascript project, `nginx-linter` is another option)

Comment: For more google "awesome-nginx github"

Comment: There is also this plugin for Prettier: https://github.com/joedeandev/prettier-plugin-nginx

Answer (score 15):

I found a few projects which might suit your needs:

1. Nginx Formatter (python) by 1connect
   you can get it [here](https://github.com/1connect/nginx-config-formatter)
2. Nginx beautifier (js/nodejs) by vasilevich
   [nginxbeautifier.com](https://nginxbeautifier.com) which lets you format configs quickly in a web browser.
   you can get a command line tool also on the same site to run it locally.

Comment: Thanks for sharing my project(nginxbeautifier) if you want to run it locally instead please visit my github page https://github.com/vasilevich/nginxbeautifier

Comment: I wrote https://github.com/beijaflor-io/conffmt too, which is a full parser and pretty-printer for any conf file

Comment: nginxbeautifier.com doesn't work. The web page is dead. I found another tool that do the same here https://nginxbeautifier.online

Answer (score 6):

If your block lines **end** with `{`'s and `}`'s, this simple indenter could help you a bit.

It **does not** format all your configs, it only fixes indentation.

Original in awk ([source)](https://evasive.ru/f29bd7ebacf24a50c582f973a55eee28.html):

```awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{sub(/^[ \t]+/,"");idx=0}
/\{/{ctx++;idx=1}
/\}/{ctx--}
{id="";for(i=idx;i<ctx;i++)id=sprintf("%s%s", id, "\t");printf "%s%s\n", id, $0}
```

Or rewritten in python:

```python
INDENT = ' ' * 4

def indent(contents):
   lines = map(str.strip, contents.splitlines())
   current_indent = 0
   for index,line in enumerate(lines):
       if (line.endswith('}')):
           current_indent -= 1

       lines[index] = current_indent * INDENT + line

       if (line.endswith('{')):
           current_indent += 1

    return ('\n').join(lines)
```

Comment: Thankyou. I spent ages trying to get vim to indent and gave up in frustration. The awk script worked great!

Answer (score 2):

There is a fork of http://jsbeautifier.org/ for nginx here: https://github.com/vasilevich/nginxbeautifier

Comment: I'm currently forking jsbeautifier out of frustration that nothing exists in the world to format this kind of config syntax. I tried jsbeautifier but it didnt work (with all settings off)

For example, #comments got started in a new line.
Like: 
#
<newline>
comments

How do you use jsbeautifier for nginx config?

Comment: @PeterWillemsen well, I am aware of limitations. Probably what saves me is that I only format large config templates and my configs are split as much as possible. So most of the time I don't stumble into problems.

Comment: Thanks, I'll just try to fork JSBeautifier, will post it when it works for NGINX files for anyone who looks for the same.

Comment: @PeterWillemsen did you ever fork that?

Comment: @PeterWillemsen did you?

Comment: @henno I did!  https://github.com/vasilevich/nginxbeautifier